# Basis free description of direct sum-tensor product natural isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory

As $- \otimes V$ is left adjoint to $\hom(V, -)$, we have a natural isomorphism $$(W \oplus Z) \otimes V \simeq (W \otimes V) \oplus (Z \otimes V).$$

We can describe one of these natural isomorphisms by specifying bases $A, B, C$ of $V, W, Z$ respectively and $a \in A, b \in B, c \in C$. This natural isomorphism is then induced by sending $\iota_W(b) \otimes c$ to $\iota_{W \otimes V}(b \otimes c)$ and $\iota_V(a) \otimes c$ to $\iota_{Z \otimes V}(a \otimes c)$.

However, this requires choosing arbitrary bases, proving that $\{a \otimes b \ | \ a \in A, b \in B\}$ is a basis for $V \otimes W$, etc. and this is ugly. Is there a pretty way to express this natural isomorphism basis free? So using only inclusions, identities, and direct sums, tensor products of maps.

EDIT: I should specify how I defined $\oplus, \otimes$. The direct sum is the coproduct in the category of vector spaces, and I use the universal construction w.r.t. bilinear maps for the tensor product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property.

Answer (score 3):

That isomorphism holds for modules as well (for example, using adjunctions), and bases are not necessary. The elements of $(W \oplus Z) \otimes V$ are finite sums of pure tensors, which are of the form $(w+z) \otimes v$. Such a pure tensor is mapped to $w \otimes v + z \otimes v \in (W \otimes V) \oplus (Z \otimes V)$.

Answer (score 0):

FYI In an additive category with direct sums all additive functors preserve direct sums, canonically by the universal property of direct sums. (It's easy to check that the diagram defining a direct sum is preserved by any functor.) So as soon as you agree that $V \otimes -$ is an additive functor, you know this fact (and the canonical isomorphism) already for formal reasons.